# iOS Push Notification: cannot find vaild connection

Tags: parse-server

I'm trying to setup push notifications on my local parse server.
I get this error when trying to send a push:

`parse-server-push-adapter APNS cannot find vaild connection for 9a86...21`

(The error repeats for every installation device token.)

Any ideas?

My server code:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '',
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Mission"]
  },
  filesAdapter: new S3Adapter(
    process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY || '',
    process.env.S3_SECRET_KEY || '',
    process.env.S3_BUCKET || '',
    {directAccess: true}
  ),
  push: {
    ios: {
      pfx: 'certificates/development.p12',
      bundleId: 'co.example.myApp',
      production: false // Dev
    }
  }
});
```

I'm pushing from my cloud code:

```
var installationQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
installationQuery.containedIn('user', specificUser);
Parse.Push.send({
  where: installationQuery,
  data: {
    "alert": "Loren ipsum ",
    "id": MyCustomId
  }
}, { useMasterKey: true }, {
  success: function() {
    console.log("Push was successful!");
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide the relevant code fragments?

Comment: were you able to resolve this? having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

What cause the error is that you have a device in the installation table that matched the filter on the `push` request that is no longer registered in Apple for your app.  When Apple receives a request for a notification to a device that is no longer registered to your application it returns that message to indicate you should take some action if it continues to happen.

In my case I have four devices registered in the installation table that matched my `push` filter and two of those devices are no longer registered in Apple for my app so every time I push it get that error for each of invalid installations.

[image: Error Message from the Parse Server Log]

[image: Matching devices in the dashboard]

I'm not sure why it happens but I've seen the following scenarios that causes a new installation record to be created that invalidates the prior installation.  It seems like something the parse service could monitor and take action for after getting so many errors for that device token with no successful pushes between errors.

1. The user deletes and re-installs the app
2. The user updates their iOS version and the `deviceToken` value is changed.
3. The connection url to the parse service is updated in the app by changing a configuration setting without having to reinstall the app.

To resolve the errors you simply need to remove the installation that matches the `deviceToken` in the error message

Answer (score 0):

You should probably configure the production certificate as well. Also note that apple now issues universal push certificates, you should use that one as it will work for acquired deviceTokens both with development and production bundles.